# field with @Transient annotation doesn't appear in returned JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I need to get a custom json containing the fields of the class **Utilisateur** plus a fied `centre_rc)` of another class **Operateur** I tried to implement this using @Transient with `centre_rc` in Utilisateur.java but when i get my json this field `centre_rc` is missing.

here is Utilisateur class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "utilisateur")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Utilisateur implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nom_utilisateur")
    private String nomUtilisateur;

    @Column(name = "prenom")
    private String prenom;

    @Column(name = "nom")
    private String nom;

    @Column(name = "date_inscription")
    private LocalDate dateInscription;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
 
    @Transient
    @JsonSerialize
    //@JsonView
    @JsonDeserialize
    @JsonInclude()
    private String centre_rc;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "utilisateurs" }, allowSetters = true)
    private Operateur operateur;
//getters & setters
}
```

here is Operateur class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "operateur")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Operateur implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "centre_rc")
    private String centreRc;

    @Column(name = "numero_rc")
    private String numeroRc;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "operateur")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "operateur" }, allowSetters = true)
    private Set<Utilisateur> utilisateurs = new HashSet<>();
    //getters & setters
}
```

In UtilisateurRepository.java here is my SQL query:

```
@Query(value = "select u.*, o.centre_rc from utilisateur u inner join operateur o on o.id=u.operateur_id", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Utilisateur> findAllOperateurs(Pageable pageable);
```

In UtilisateurResource.java

```
@GetMapping("/utilisateursOperateurs")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Utilisateur>> getAllUtilisateursCalledOperateurs(
        @org.springdoc.api.annotations.ParameterObject Pageable pageable
    ) {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Utilisateurs");
        Page<Utilisateur> page = utilisateurRepository.findAllOperateurs(pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }
```

the result of this query return something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nomUtilisateur": "e-business Granite drive",
    "prenom": "context-sensitive strategic calculate",
    "nom": "maximized Oberkampf withdrawal",
    "dateInscription": "2022-03-11",
    "password": "viral",
    "operateur": {
      "id": 8,
      "centreRc": "parsing primary invoice",
      "numeroRc": "Harpe"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Transient
@JsonProperty
private String centre_rc;
```

You can try to use this annotation `@JsonProperty`, I use this in my project and it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! `centre_rc` appears now in json but it has null value. like this :            `{
    "id": 3,
    "nomUtilisateur": "e-business Granite drive",
    "prenom": "context-sensitive strategic calculate",
    "nom": "maximized Oberkampf withdrawal",
    "dateInscription": "2022-03-11",
    "password": "viral",
    "centre_rc": null,
    "operateur": {
      "id": 8,
      "centreRc": "parsing primary invoice",
      "numeroRc": "Harpe"
    }
  }`

Comment: Then you should set the value of this field, for instance, `select operateur.centre_rc as utilisateur.centre_rc `

Comment: I get this error : `could not prepare statement; SQL [select u.*, o.centre_rc as u.centre_rc from utilisateur u inner join operateur o on o.id=u.operateur_id limit ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement`

Comment: here is the full project https://github.com/hamaarouf/userAuth.git if you want to test it please maybe I'm messing something. I guess the problem comes from `o.centre_rc` in sql query because it can't be mapped to `centre_rc` in Utilisateur class

Comment: u should not use `select u.* `, because it contains the property `u.centre_rc`, u can modified and try it again. If this still not work, I think I need to try it on my own computer later, this is also new to me.

Comment: the same error `could not prepare statement; SQL [select u.nom_utilisateur, u.nom, u.prenom, u.date_inscription, u.password, o.centre_rc as u.centre_rc from utilisateur u inner join operateur o on o.id=u.operateur_id limit ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement` I guess it's obvious because there is no column in utilisateur table called `centre_rc`

Comment: You're right, I have a solution here, but I don't think it's the best way.You can change the getter method of this `centreRc` property,  just return the value you want

Answer (score 0):

Jackson might not serialize the field because the following field is null. Try removing @JsonInclude() annotation from the field like this

```
@Transient
@JsonSerialize
@JsonDeserialize
private String centre_rc;
```

And add @JsonInclude annotation at the class level

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "utilisateur")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Utilisateur implements Serializable {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! unfortunately, it doesn't appear in json